# ajax image upload to database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm unable to upload the image by ajax,it always redirect to the page whenever I click submit button and the data is not added to the database as well.

> form

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" id="ImageUploadForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <input type="text" name="caption" id="caption">
 <input type="file" name="image" id="ImageBrowse"/>
 <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Save" />  
</form>
```

> ajax

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    $("#imageUploadForm").on('submit',(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: "<?php echo base_url();?>adminpromisess/addgal",
            type: "POST",
            data:  new FormData(this),
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData:false,
            success: function(data) {
                alert(data);
                //$("#gallery-form").load(".gallery-form");
            },
            error: function() {
            }           
        });
    }));
});
```

*add data to database function (controller)*

```
 public function addgal(){
     $caption = $this->input->post('caption');
     $promises = 00;
     $description = $this->input->post('description');
     $image = $_FILES['image']['name'];
     if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], 'assets/img/upload/promises_image/'.$image)){

         $data = array(
         'caption' => $caption,
         'promises' => $promises,
         'gal_desc' => $description,
         'image' => $image
         );
         $result = $this->adminpromisesmodel->addGallery($data);
     }else{
         echo "Fail to upload file";
         die();
     }
 }
```

note:model (query) to save the database is correct so i didn't post it

Comment: So what can you see in 1. your http servers error log file and 2. your browsers development console?

Comment: nothing on 2.
but how to see http servers error log file

Comment: That is impossible. At least you must see the network requests in your browsers console.

Comment: About the http servers error log file - well it is a log file that your http server writes, dumping all php and networking issues in there (in a normal setup). The default location is something like `/var/log/apache2/error.log`.  So you have to locate it on the server and you should _always_ monitor it when doing php development. Best is to use something like `tail -f <logfile>` for such task...

Comment: you made a typo (see my answer), and yes you should learn to use the browser and server logs because it will make solving this kind of issue easy.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$('#imageUploadForm').on('submit', function(ev){
  ev.preventDefault();
  var forms = document.querySelector('form#imageUploadForm');
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var formDatas = new FormData(forms);
  request.open('post','yourControllerFunction');
  request.send(formDatas);
  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (request.readyState === 4) {
    if (request.status === 200) {

    //Request was OK show success message

    } else {
    // Request not OK, show error message

    }
  }
});
```

In your controller's action (its a cakephp code)

```
if($this->request->is('post')){
   $data = $this->request->data;
   echo "<pre>",print_r($data),"</pre>";
   //You should be able to see file data in this array
}
```

You can handle it just like a direct form submission on your controller

Answer (score 0):

`ImageUploadForm` != `imageUploadForm`

Fix that typo causing the [dead code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unreachable_code) (the form tag) to run and things should work as you expect.
Your browser, development tools, network tab should have shown a POST instead of a XHR because of that issue.

Comment: That does not really matter, since `e.preventDefault();` prevents the normal form submission.

Comment: I would not exactly call this "dead code", but the point here is: _this does not answer the question at all._

Comment: Well spotted. Still no idea why you call that "dead code", but anyway, the OP should indeed see a POST request in the browsers console. And btw: "updated to make it more clear..." Let's face it: this is a compeltely _different_ answer to what you wrote before :-)